# Inherit XAML layout / Masterpage

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a storyboard animation in a popup and I want this to be on every page in the application. How can I do this without copy pasting the animation into every XAML and all the code-behind logic to control the animation. I also have buttons that should be on every page as well in certain positions. Is there a better way to do this than duplicating code? I'm already inheriting from PhoneApplicationPage but that only handles the code-behind stuff and no the XAML layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create UserControl for your animation rather than duplicating code, call this User Control in other user controls or pages.

To add User Control right click your project Add then New Item then Silverlight User Control, name your control accordingly for example "AnimationUserControl" finally click Add. Do your animation work in this new User Control to call this new User Control in other Controls you have to add reference of you project into User Control where u are calling AnimationUserControl for example in MainPage.xaml like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Com.Softechww.Controls.Silverlight.Scheduler.Scheduler"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ProjectNameSpace" Width="800" Height="450" >
```

add new line with "xmlns:local" which value is referring you projects root, project namespace can be found by right clicking project file in Visual Studio under Silverlight then Default namespace.

now simply call it below in User Control like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <local:AnimationUserControl/>
</Grid>
```

It should work.